# xslt 2.0 month name in French or German

Tags: xslt, tomcat, xslt-2.0, apache-fop, saxon

I’m using xslt fn:formate-dateTime() to get the current date and time, for English it’s works fine.

But everytime I try to get the month name in different languages (fr, de, etc), I will just get the current date and time with [Language: en] in the front and couldn’t get the month name in that language.

Date Created: [Language: en] 06/April/2011

Here is my code, Could someone tell me what I’m doing wrong here.

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(current-dateTime(),
                                      '[D01]/[MNn]/[Y0001]',
                                      ’de’,
                                      ’AD’,
                                      ’DE’)"/>
```

Or

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(current-dateTime (),
                                      '[D01]/[MNn]/[Y0001]',
                                      ’fr’,
                                      ’AD’,
                                      ’FR’)"/>
```

I’m using Saxon 9 with Fop 1.0 running on tomcat 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually that information about Saxon is a little out of date (as is the information at http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/extensibility/localizing.xml - embarrassing).

But we need to know which specific Saxon release you are using: it changed between 9.1 and 9.2, and it's different between Home Edition and Professional Edition. In the current release, 9.3, support for a number of common languages such as de and fr is available "out of the box" with Saxon-PE and Saxon-EE, but has to be configured manually from source code with Saxon-HE, by writing a LocalizerFactory and registering it with the Configuration.

Comment: +1 Well, just for been Michael Kay. How could this be not correct?

Comment: Thanks Michael,I'm using Saxon-HE 9.3 jar.so I guess I'll have to build it from source code.

Comment: This seems to still be the case in Saxon-HE 10.5.

Comment: The relevant documentation is now at https://saxonica.com/documentation10/index.html#!extensibility/config-extend/localizing

Comment: Sample source code for Saxon-HE as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/64469629/2720554 is available at https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/repository/he/revisions/master/show/latest10/hej/net/sf/saxon/option/local

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#lang-cal-country

> The set of languages, calendars, and
>   countries that are supported in the
>   date formatting functions is
>   implementation-defined. When any of
>   these arguments is omitted or is an
>   empty sequence, an
>   implementation-defined default value
>   is used.
>
> If the fallback representation uses a
>   different calendar from that
>   requested, the output string must be
>   prefixed with `[Calendar: X]` where X
>   identifies the calendar actually used.
>   The string `Calendar` should be
>   localized using the requested language
>   if available. If the fallback
>   representation uses a different
>   language from that requested, the
>   output string should be prefixed with
>   `[Language: Y]` where Y identifies the
>   language actually used. The string
>   `Language` may be localized in an
>   implementation-dependent way. If a
>   particular component of the value
>   cannot be output in the requested
>   format, it should be output in the
>   default format for that component.

From http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/functions/intro/format-dateTime.xml

> Formats a date, using a format
>   controlled by the picture string. If
>   no language is specified, the value is
>   taken from the current Java locale. If
>   the language (explicitly supplied or
>   defaulted) is other than "en", the
>   system tries to locate a class named
>   `net.sf.saxon.number.Numberer_XX`
>   where XX is the language; this class
>   must provide methods to perform the
>   localization.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Alejandro,I have seen this two links before, I guess it's the version of Saxon I am running have some limitation.

Comment: @Jimmy: No problem. You got your answer from Dr. Kay anyway!