# How to set language data with Saxon HE 10.2?

Tags: xslt, internationalization, saxon

How can I set language data correctly with Saxon HE 10.2? I need the XSLT Processor to output the current date with a month name written out in German, like `21. Oktober 2020`. Unfortunately, the processor outputs
`[Language: en]21. October 2020`.
Saxon PE gives the desired output out of the box.
This is my XSLT code:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="3.0">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(current-dateTime(), '[D]. [MNn] [Y]', 'de', (), ())"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The test XML source code file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root/>
```

In Linux, I run `java -cp $xsltProc $class -s:source.xml -xsl:stylesheet.xslt -o:result`.
`$xsltProc` is the path to the file `saxon-he-10.2.jar`.
`$class` is `net.sf.saxon.Transform`.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://www.saxonica.com/documentation/#!extensibility/config-extend/localizing/other-numberings suggests that using https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/repository/he/revisions/master/entry/latest10/hej/net/sf/saxon/option/local/Numberer_de.java "it is possible to configure [support for de] by writing a subclass of LocalizerFactory and registering it with the Configuration".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To support German date formats "out of the box", you need Saxon-PE or higher.

See https://saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!extensibility/config-extend/localizing/other-numberings

If you want this with Saxon-HE, you can compile the open source code for class `net.sf.saxon.option.local.Numberer_de` and register it with the Configuration:

```
configuration.setLocalizerFactory(new LocalizerFactory() {
   public Numberer getNumberer(String language, String country) {
       if (lang.equals("de")) {
           return new Numberer_de();
       } else {
           ...
       }
   });
```

The `Numberer` code is available at https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon/repository/he/revisions/master/entry/latest10/hej/net/sf/saxon/option/local/Numberer_de.java

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following with the example files from the original question, but the Configuration was never invoked.
I presume the Configuration needs to be registered somehow?

```
final Configuration config = new Configuration();
/**/                config.setLocalizerFactory(new LocalizerFactory() {
    public Numberer getNumberer(final String language, final String country) {
        if (language.equals("de")) {
            return  Numberer_de.getInstance();
        } else {
            return  null;
        }
    }
});

Transform.main(new String[] {
        "-s:source.xml",
        "-xsl:stylesheet.xslt",
        "-o:result.txt"
});
```